# Computing c = √(a × b) in parallel using nested parallelism

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing

Let's say we have two vectors A=(ai) and B=(bi), each of size n and we have to compute a new vector C=(ci) as  = √( × ) for(i=1,...,n)

**Main question:** What would be the best way to compute the ci in parallel (using nested parallelism, i.e. using sync and spawn).

I think the below  understanding is correct about the computation

```
for (i = 1 to n) {
    C[i] = Math.sqrt(A[i] * B[i]);
}
```

And is there any way to use parallel for loops to compute `C` in parallel ?

If so, I think the approach will be the following:

```
parallel for (i = 1 to n) {
    C[i] = Math.sqrt(A[i] * B[i]);
}
```

Is it correct ?

Comment: No any specific language for now. Just wanted to know an approach.

Comment: Just a side note on notation: the cross `×` is typically used to indicate cross-product, but here it seems you mean dot product, which is often indicated by a centered dot `·`.

Comment: Yeah. But ai and bi are not vectors so I think it's fine here. is it correct ?

Comment: You might want to consider ILP/SIMD for that task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by *best* you mean *fastest*, the usual approach would be to divide `A` and `B` into chunks, spawn a separate thread for handling each of these chunks in parallel, and wait for all the threads to finish their tasks.

The optimal number of chunks for such computation, most likely, will be the number of CPU cores you have on your computer. So, the pseudocode would look like:

```
chunkSize = ceiling(n / numberOfCPUs)
for (t = 1 to numberOfCPUs) {
    startIndex = (t - 1) * chunkSize + 1
    size = min(chunkSize, C.size - startIndex + 1)
    threads.add(Thread.spawn(startIndex, size))
}
threads.join()
```

Where each thread, provided with the `startIndex` and `size`, computes:

```
for (i = startIndex to startIndex + size) {
    C[i] = Math.sqrt(A[i] * B[i])
}
```

Another approach would be to have a pool of threads and give those threads a single shared queue of indices `1, 2, ... n`. Each thread on each iteration polls the top index (let it be `i`) and calculates `C[i]`. As soon as the queue is empty, the work is done. The problem here is that you need additional synchronization mechanism that would guarantee that every index is processed by exactly one thread. For some simple tasks (like yours) such mechanism might consume more resources than actual calculation, but for relatively long-running tasks it works pretty well.

There's a mutual approach when you break the initial set of tasks into chunks, provide each thread in the pool with its own chunk, but when a thread is done with its chunk, it starts 'stealing' tasks from other threads in order not to sit idle. On many real tasks it gives better results than either of previous approaches.

Comment: having chunks would be the first choice. Nice explanation on that. Wanted to see if there is any other way.

Comment: Yep, there're others, I've added a couple of most common.